# Как обратиться к определенному блоку с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript

Имеются блоки:

```
<div class="rowwrapper2">
    <div onclick="show1()"></div>
    <div onclick="show1()"></div>
    <div onclick="show1()"></div>
    <div onclick="show1()"></div>
```

Имеется функция на JS:

```
function show1(){
var div = document.querySelectorAll(".rowwrapper2 div")[0];
var a = div.getAttribute("name");
alert(a);}
```

С таким кодом он будет выводить только атрибут "name" первого блока вне зависимости от того, на какой блок будет нажатие. Как исправить так, чтобы он выводил атрибут "name" нужного мне блока при нажатии на него, а не первого?

Comment: Через цикл, как вариант

Comment: ваш ответ тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/ и тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ Или ждите пока придет тот, у кого будет время и желание разжевать.